# How to use size-limit package?

Tags: reactjs, npm, config, yarnpkg, package.json

I have installed the npm package size-limit to monitor the size of my application. Following their documentation, I've written this in my package.json:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "size": "size-limit"
  },
  
  "size-limit": [
    {
      "path": "./src/index.tsx",
      "limit": "120 KB"
    }
  ],
```

But when running `yarn size` I receive the following error:

> `/bin/sh: size-limit: command not found`.

Weird. When directly running `yarn size-limit` I have:

> `error Command "size-limit" not found.`

How to fix this?

Comment: Have you you tried running: `yarn run size`

Comment: Yes. With no success, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran into the same error while trying to run `yarn size` for a React app. Solved it by installing size-limit and @size-limit/preset-app as dev dependencies:

`yarn add size-limit @size-limit/preset-app --dev`

Then:

1. add size-limit as a configuration in package.json
2. add the size script

(Just like you've done, but my path is `build/static/**/*.{js,css,svg,woff,woff2,png,ttf,html}`)

```
{
...
 "size-limit": [
    {
      "path": "..."
    }
  ],
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "size": "yarn build && size-limit"
  }
...
}
```

Reference:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/size-limit/v/0.19.3
- https://medium.com/@eferhatg/create-react-app-continuous-integration-config-with-circleci-and-aws-2b0238cde169

Running `yarn size` now works:

[image: Yarn size result]

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following,

- check if all dependencies, if not install `yarn install`
- try with `yarn run size` (as @RobC pointed out)
- delete `node_modules` folder and again install the dependencies
- check if the package was installed correctly

Now `yarn size` should work.

Comment: No, everything was installed (I've run yarn install to double check though). When running yarn size, I still have: /bin/sh: size-limit: command not found

Comment: @DoneDeal0 did u try deleting the complete `node_modules` folder and install again ?

Comment: Yes. The issue persists :(.

Comment: can u try with `npm` once, this seems similar https://github.com/postlight/headless-wp-starter/issues/68